# What is the purpose of defining vector spaces on a noncommutative division ring? Please give me some examples

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am currently in linear algebra chapter of Hungerford's Algebra textbook. In here vector space is generally defined on arbitrary(I mean, it can be noncommutative) division ring. With this 'left vector space on a division ring' structure, matrix representation of a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces(free module with finite basis) must be constructed by rows. More specifically, the correspondence between linear maps and their matrix representations works well only when we construct the matrix representation of the given linear map by putting the coordinate representation of the image of each basis elements in domain rowisely.
This makes me quite confused. If the underlying ring is commutative(in particular if it is a field), the columnwise construction what we usually do in elementary linear algebra works well. I think this construction works more naturally when we interpret matrix itself as a linear map.
So I have curiosity whether there is any important purpose for defining vector spaces and matrix representation with more general setting.

Comment: Wedderburn's theorem says that a semisimple artinian ring is isomorphic to the product of endomorphism rings of finite dimensional vector spaces over division rings.

Comment: If you want to study division rings this is an important result. If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are division rings with centers equal to a common field $K$ and they are both finite-dimensional over $K$ then the $K$-algebra $D_1 \otimes_{K} D_2$ is isomorphic to ${\rm M}_n(D_3)$ for a positive  integer $n$ and division ring $D_3$ with center $K$ that is finite-dimensional over $K$. The mapping $(D_1,D_2) \mapsto D_3$ is a *group law* on (isomorphism classes of) division rings with center $K$ that are finite-dimensional over $K$. The inverse of $D$ is its opposite ring $D^{\rm op}$. Google "Brauer group".

Comment: Division rings also show up naturally when we study representation theory of finite groups over non-algebraically closed fields.